# How to Git Fetch <remote> using libgit2sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

My existing Fetch method looks like this.

```
public void Fetch(string remote) => CommandLine.Run($"git fetch {remote}", _repoFolder);
```

I would like to implement the same feature using libgit2sharp.

This is what I have came up with:

```
public void Fetch(string remote)
{
    var repo = new Repository(_folder);
    var options = new FetchOptions();
    options.Prune = true;
    options.TagFetchMode = TagFetchMode.Auto;
    var refSpecs = $"+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/{remote}/*";
    Commands.Fetch(repo, remote, new [] {refSpecs}, options, "Fetching remote");
}
```

However this fails with the following error message:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'authentication cancelled'`

I have also tried with the libgit2sharp-ssh package, where the result is error code 401 (unathorized client).

I presume the git command line tool works because it knows how to authorize the access (since there is already a remote). How can I achieve the same using libgit2sharp?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like

```cs
using(var repo = new Repository(_folder))
{
    var options = new FetchOptions();
    options.Prune = true;
    options.TagFetchMode = TagFetchMode.Auto;
    options.CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler(
        (url, usernameFromUrl, types) =>
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
            {
                Username = "username",
                Password = "password"
            });

    var remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
    var msg = "Fetching remote";
    var refSpecs = remote.FetchRefSpecs.Select(x => x.Specification);
    Commands.Fetch(repo, remote.Name, refSpecs, options, msg);                
}
```